# How to Json Element is present or not using C# (With Newtonsoft NugetPackages)

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

I have Json file, where i am trying the parse the data of the json file for database update with some data contions, Currently i want to check an particular element exists or not.In my current Json data, Under the Operation Node the accessRef can exist in the file or may not exist completely.So how would check the condtion. Kindly suggest me.

Below is the Json file

```
{
   "PLMXML":{
      "language":"en-us",
      "time":"16:50:15",
      "schemaVersion":"6",
      "author":"Development(-2069033203)",
      "date":"2020-05-22",
      "Header":{
             "id":"id1",
             "traverseRootRefs":"#id6",
             "transferContext":"CLM"
          },
      "Operation":{
             "id":"id21",
             "name":"PD_Op2",
             "subType":"BS4_BaOP",
             "accessRefs":"#id18",
             "catalogueId":"70700000209604",
             "ApplicationRef":{
                "application":"Teamcenter",
                "label":"yDX58d4FIpN8QD",
                "version":"yDX58d4FIpN8QD"
             }
          }
      }
}
```

Below the Code which i am trying perform

```
public void Readjsonfile(string jsondata)
{   var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<plmxmldatamodel>(jsondata);             
    Console.WriteLine("RootRef: " + message.PLMXML.Header.traverseRootRefs);
    Console.WriteLine("OccurenceId: "+message.PLMXML.ProductView.Operation.id);
// I want to check whtether is accessrefs is present or not inside the Operation element
}    
//fuction1
public class Header
{       public string traverseRootRefs { get; set; }    
}
//fuction2
public class Operation
{   public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string subType { get; set; }
    public string accessRefs { get; set; }
    public string catalogueId { get; set; }
}
//fuction3
public class PLMXML
{
    public string language { get; set; }
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public Operation Operation { get; set; }
}
//fuction4
public class plmxmldatamodel
{
    public PLMXML PLMXML { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If empty/null value for `accessRefs` is a valid situation (i.e. `... "'accessRefs':, ..."`) then you can use [JSON Path](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to check if it exists:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsondata);
if(jObj.SelectToken("$.PLMXML.Operation.accessRefs") != null)
{
    // do what you want to do if accessRefs exists
}
```

Otherwise just check for `message.PLMXML.ProductView.Operation.accessRefs` not being null:

```
if(message.PLMXML.ProductView.Operation.accessRefs != null)
{
    // do what you want to do if accessRefs exists
}
```

Comment: Hi @Guru Stron, Yes as you suggested I would need to check being null in my i.e the 2nd option you suggested.But currently I not knowing how do I check that.I tried if(message.PLM

Comment: Hi @user1539205!

Comment: Hi @Guru Stron, Yes as you suggested, I would need to check being null in my i.e the 2nd option you suggested.But currently I not knowing how do I check that.I tried if(message.PLMXML.Operation.accessRefs == null). Kindly suggest if doing wrong here

Comment: @user1539205 what do you mean by not working? the check you provided is checking for object being null, so it will return `true` if `accessRefs` is not present.

Comment: @user1539205 was glad to help!